# Pattern matching on a shapeless type cast ok?

Tags: scala, shapeless

All of the examples I can find with google of the use of Typeable's cast involve a for expression.  This is working for me, but I was wondering if this is ok.  I'm brand new to shapeless:  That's my first import in the lib.

```scala
import shapeless.Typeable._

val blarg: Future[Any] = (worker ? ListOfLongsPlx(foo)) // I know Any === Try[List[Long]]
blarg.map {
  _.cast[Try[List[Long]]] match {
    case Some(Success(xs)) => xs
    case Some(Failure(f)) => /* reporting the failure or just default: */ ;  List()
    case None => /*reporting bad cast just a default: */ List()
  }
}
```

Should I expect problems with this pattern?

To be clear, this is passing my tests.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is fine (although I don't understand how that specific code can work since `Try` isn't `Future`), but you can actually get a slightly nicer syntax in the pattern match with `TypeCase`:

```
import shapeless.TypeCase
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success, Try }

val thing: Any = Try(List(1L, 2L))

val TryListLongCase = TypeCase[Try[List[Long]]]

thing match {
  case TryListLongCase(Success(xs)) => xs
  case TryListLongCase(Failure(f)) => println(f); Nil
  case _ => println("Some unexpected thing"); Nil
}
```

And the result will be appropriately typed as a `List[Long]`.

Comment: he actor I am referencing does return a try, so in my real project, I'm actually mapping a future[try[list[long]]] to a future[httpresponse], but I stripped out the irrelevant details.

Comment: Oh, right—I must have been reading too quickly. Everything else in my answer still stands, though.